# How can I pull from master branch with git?

Tags: git, error-handling, pull

I try to pull from my master branch, but I get the error message:

```
$ git --no-optional-locks -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree fetch origin 

error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/navigation': is at 1234566753 but expected 5434623423 From https://bitbucket.org/myproject  ! 12345..8f1b648  navigation -> origin/navigation  (unable to update local ref) Completed with errors, see above
```

What can I do?

Comment: Why are you using `--no-optional-locks` here? (It should work—as in, it should do nothing; the locks aren't optional so there are no optional locks to omit—but it's also unnecessary.) This particular error should not occur in general and should not repeat if you repeat the `git fetch` operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run:

```
 git gc --prune=now
```

and delete `.git/refs/remote/origin`

Comment: does this delete anything important?

Comment: @fala do the backup if you have some doubts